# Same algorithm, same string, same salt, different result?

Tags: php, encryption, blowfish

I'm using the Blowfish algorithm for encrypting passwords in my application.

After reinstalling Ubuntu on the server, the output of this algorithm has changed - though I'm trying the same string and the same salt.

Any ideas on why this happens or how to solve it?
Thanks in advance.

I'm using the native PHP crypt implementation on an Ubuntu Server (11.04). Before I had the version 10.10.

Comment: What tool are you using to do the encryption/decryption? The output changes, but what happens if you try to decrypt it?

Comment: With no commands used, tool versions, or other details, the chance of you getting this answered is absolutely ZERO

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I changed it.
Giacomo, as I'm using the PHP crypt function, there's no decrypting.

Comment: Does the decryption still work?  Encryption can end up encrypting to different strings, but I think you will find that it decrypts just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you change the encoding type.
Make sure that you are using the same encodind type for the both encrypt operation.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but that's not it. I checked all the encodings, they're all the same.